# Enforce charset for decoding html in QT webkit

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

I use qt web kit api to convert html files to pdf.

The problem that I am facing is of character corruption of south east asian characters.

Right now I am manually setting the character set for the html files in following way:

```
QWebSettings objWebSettings = objQWebPage.settings();
    objWebSettings.setDefaultTextEncoding("GB18030");
```

but the above code fails for html files of the following type:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body class='hmmessage'><div dir='ltr'>
<br><br><div><hr id="stopSpelling">From: sunbeam_is_me@hotmail.com<br>To: sunbeam0606@gmail.com<br>Subject: <br>Date: Thu, 10 Nov 2011 14:53:17 +0800<br><br>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=unicode">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft SafeHTML">
<style>
.ExternalClass .ecxhmmessage P
{padding:0px;}
.ExternalClass body.ecxhmmessage
{font-size:10pt;font-family:Tahoma;}

</style>

<div dir="ltr">
逆势大；你是我的阿</div></div></div></body>
</html>
```

To me it looks like the webkit engine gives precedence to the 'meta' header that specifies the charset and ignores the encoding passed by me.

Is there a way I can enforce my encoding on webkit engine?

Thanks in advance

Ashish

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the documents into UTF-8 before sending to QWebPage.

This could be done using `QTextStream` and calling [`QTextStream::setCodec`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextstream.html#setCodec-2) to set the character encoding.